# C - conditional statement & strcmp & NULL string

Tags: c, null, strcmp

How safe would be to do something like:

```
if (flag_val != NULL && strcmp (val, flag_val) == 0) {
   // something
} else {
   // something else
}
```

Knowing that sometimes `flag_val` will be `NULL` and sometimes not.

I know it will check first if `flag_val != NULL`, if it evaluates false, it shouldn't check the second condition right?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Correct, if flag_val is NULL then the && operator will short-circuit.  As long as flag_val can't be changed by some other thread, this is safe code.

Answer (score 1):

If `flag_val != NULL` evaluates to false, that is, `flag_val` is `NULL`, then short circuit logic will stop the evaluation of the rest of the expression (since the entire condition cannot be true).  What you're doing is fine.